# Biztalk 2013: the stupidity behind the SFTP adapter implementation (read-only handling)

Tags: biztalk, sftp, biztalk-2013

Microsoft introduced the concept of "Read-only" handling in their FTP adapter in BizTalk 2010.  With the release of BizTalk 2013, they implemented the SFTP adapter, but without inheriting all the functionality of their mature FTP adapter.   Are they assuming that those who will use the SFTP adapter, will not be burdened by the same issues that plagued the earlier versions of the FTP adapter?

Now that I got that out of my system, I am looking at implementing an SFTP adapter, such as Blogical's, however, that was only written for BTS 2010, and doesn't seem to work with 2013.
I was able to recompile the source for .net 4.5, but cant seem to figure out how to install it.  Looking for suggestions on either how to do that, or any alternative ways of dealing with read-only SFTP scenarios on BTS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

One other option is the /n software SFTP adapter. Full disclosure I work for nsoftware but our adapter has been around for years and is full featured. It is not free, but would do what you need and supports BizTalk 2013. Specifically, there's a DeleteMode property to control when files are deleted from the server. We have a [tutorial](http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/tutorials/biztalksftpadapter.aspx) to help people getting started as well.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this product keep track of files that it has already downloaded, to prevent it duplicate downloads?

Comment: There is a DownloadCacheFile setting that can be specified in the Other proprety of the adapter (in the Tuning section) like:
`DownloadCacheFile=c:\cache.txt`
which will keep a list of downloaded files so each file is only downloaded once. This is based on the filename.

Answer (score 1):

True, but in all fairness, FTPS and SFTP are completely different, as are the Adapters.

I'd recommend submitting feedback on Connect to extend the file logging feature to the SFTP Adapter.

As for the Blogical Adapter, the Adapter registration procedure is unchanged from 2010 to 2013 (actually, save 64vs32bit but, it's unchanged since 2004).  If you had a specific problem, you can open a new thread.  Maybe we can help with that.

Comment: FTP. SFTP, FTPS are only concerned with the connection and session transport layer.  What is encapsulated inside these is the same across the board.  File transfer methods are the same in each, so if you are going to sell an FTP client SW, for example, you are not going to treat the core functionality differently between the types.  It's like selling cars and saying that if you want a red one, it only comes with manual transmission.